# How to make a line border with circles in html?

Tags: html, css

How to make the following where each div has a "circle" connected to lines on the left side of multiple divs?

An example of this is here:
https://www.ruxit.com/ruxit/survey.html

How to replicate this effect/border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the element in question on the website you provided you can see that the circle is done using a `:before` pseudo element and the line is done using the `:after` pseudo element.

Here is a quick mock up on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaK5h/2/)

CSS:

```
.border:before
{
    background-color:blue;
    width:1.2em;
    height:1.2em;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.border:after
{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    background-color:blue;
    height:100%;
    width: 1px;
    left:0.55em;
    margin-top:-1px;
    position:relative;
}
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/TaK5h/4/) is an improved version by [King Kong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king) using border-left, which solves the problem of `:after` not appearing when using long strings:

HTML:

```
<div class="border" style="height:75px;">hey</div>
<div class="border" style="height:50px;">hey2</div>
<div class="border" style="height:150px;">hey3</div>
<div class="border end">done</div>
```

CSS:

```
.border {
    padding-left:20px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0.6em;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.border:not(.end) {    
    border-left:1px solid blue;        
}
.border:before
{
    background-color:blue;
    width:1.2em;
    height:1.2em;
    content:'';    
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:-0.6em;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: here is another approach using `border-left` to render the vertical line http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/TaK5h/4/

Comment: note that the `:after` is not rendered correctly when the text is long, you can see the issue in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/TaK5h/5/

Comment: @KingKing Thanks, for pointing that out. Also, I didn't know about that ':not()' trick. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

html

```
 <div class="line">
   <div class="col3"><span class="circle"></span></div>
   <div class="col3"><span class="circle"></span></div>
   <div class="col3"><span class="circle"></span></div>
   <div class="col3"><span class="circle"></span></div>
 </div>
```

css

```
.line .col3{
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   top: -8px;
   width: 288px;
}
```

see jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/n5m7x/